# How to put a model in a T-pose automatically?

Tags: export, rigging, armature, unity

Is there a way to force a model to a T-pose? I need my model to be in a T-pose so that I can export it to Unity for a humanoid rig. But putting a model in a T-pose manually is hard.

So is there a way to do this automatically (something except makewalk script)?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is your model rigged already? Or are you exporting it so that it can be rigged in Unity?

Comment: Putting a model in a t-pose manually is not hard. You said you wanted to use it as a humanoid rig. Is it a model, or an armature?

Comment: @ Naioai Studios you cant rig in unity , rigged model must be imported to unity   @Vince Scalia it is a rigged model as you see in picture

Comment: uh... so whats wrong with it?

Comment: i putted this in T pose by hand wanted to know how to do this automatically , and the fingers are not aligned too

Answer (score 6):

If the armature was created (*Edit Mode*) in T-pose, you can easily get it back in armature tab by clicking *Rest Position* button and get your pose again with *Pose Position* button.

If you need the T-pose as a pose, select all bones (with <kbd>A</kbd> ) in *Pose Mode* and <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> , <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> to clear all transforms. You can then create a T-pose in the *Pose Library* to activate it easily.

Comment: Doesn't work with Rigify in 2.81 -- just leaves it in the A pose it came in.

Answer (score 0):

here is a link to a video where he resets the Rest Position https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iMVs6BP1Q48&ab_channel=Chris%27Tutorials

Comment: Add a brief summary of the content as this is a link-only answer.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/141079)